# How can I evenly fan out a hand of cards?

Tags: mathematics

Given a set of playing cards (rectangle images with a width and height) how can I rotate and position each one so that they appear in a 'fan' pattern, much like you would hold a hand of cards in real life. What math is needed to do this?

**UPDATE**

Here is the final, in browser implementation in JavaScript: https://cosmicrealms.com/blog/2013/03/16/hand-of-cards/
and
http://jsfiddle.net/tyyvk/108/

Comment: Sir, you seem to have too many aces in your hand. Please step away from the table.

Comment: The fiddle needs to be updated to use a later version of MooTools.

Comment: Related: [How can I approximate an “opening fan”-transformation?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/62526/7804)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Theory**

Since you didn't specify in what platform you're implementing this, I'll give a description of the algorithm in a language-agnostic way:

1. First **stack every card** on top of each other by giving them the same initial position.
2. Then for each card **apply a rotation** (usually *centered around one of the bottom corners*, but moving this origin around will essentialy allow you to tweak the look of the fan).
3. **Increment the angle of rotation between each call**, depending on the number of cards and how much you want them to be spread.

That the *rotation is centered around one of the card's bottom corners* (or near the corner) should be evident from looking at it:

[image]

---

**Implementation**

As for how to implement this, it depends on your platform. On XNA you can simply use the Origin parameter of `SpriteBatch.Draw` to change the center of your rotation.

Here's what I got with the following code (with a few tweaks to the origin to make it look better - basically the origin starts near the right corner and ends up near the left corner):

```cs
int cards = 20;
float range = MathHelper.ToRadians(90);
float initialAngle = MathHelper.ToRadians(-45);
float increment = range / cards;
Vector2 leftCorner = new Vector2(0, texture.Height * 0.9f);
Vector2 rightCorner = new Vector2(texture.Width, texture.Height * 0.9f);
Vector2 fanPosition = new Vector2(400, 300);
spriteBatch.Begin();
for (float angle = 0; angle < range; angle+=increment)
{
    float cardAngle = initialAngle + angle;
    Vector2 cardOrigin = Vector2.Lerp(rightCorner, leftCorner, angle / range);
    spriteBatch.Draw(texture, fanPosition, null, Color.White, cardAngle, cardOrigin, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
}
spriteBatch.End();
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: I'd add that the look can be tweaked by using a different centre of rotation, if you want to span a smaller arc you should use a rotation point that lies below the card.

Comment: @eBusiness You're right, I'll add that in.

Comment: Thanks a lot David! I've implemented the code you've shown in JavaScript here: http://jsfiddle.net/tyyvk/7/